# I'm trying to stream the following url in ios but it won't play

Tags: ios, audio, avplayer, aac

the audio i want to stream is:http://streamer2.ultapulta.com:8001

I've tried other streaming links and they work in my code.

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:streamUrl];

```
_myItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
_mySound = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:_myItem];

[_mySound play]
```

I believe the stream is in AAC format. What should I do

Comment: Try using the `status` and `error` properties of the `AVPlayer` to see if that gives you more information.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [StreamingKit](https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit)

Example like in documentation:

```
STKAudioPlayer* audioPlayer = [[STKAudioPlayer alloc] init];
[audioPlayer queue:@"http://streamer2.ultapulta.com:8001"];
```

And it's better to have `audioPlayer` as class property.

Comment: No luck with StreamingKit either. It works with other url, but not mine. And I know mine does stream because vlc has no trouble with it.

Comment: I ended up using the libvlc https://wiki.videolan.org/VLCKit/#Basic_usage_in_your_application